# how to use a setter for vector of an object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector, std

```
std::vector<Game*> games;
```

I have the following setter:

```
void Instructor::setGames(const std::vector<Game *> &value)
{
    games = value;
}
```

And I am trying to use it like this:

```
 Game g1, g2, g3;
std::vector <Game> gameSet;
    gameSet.push_back(g1);
    gameSet.push_back(g2);
    gameSet.push_back(g3);
    i.setGames(&gameSet);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Instructor::setGames(std::vector<Game>*)’
     i.setGames(&gameSet);
```

This doesn't work either.

```
 i.setGames(gameSet);
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to fix this without changing the `std::vector<Game*> games;`

Comment: `std::vector<Game *>` and `std::vector<Game>*` are two different types

Comment: Ah but when I change ```std::vector <Game> gameSet;``` to ```<Game*>```, I get errors on push_back even if I use a reference @PeterT

Comment: The question is what is `games`, is it `std::vector<Game*>` or a `std::vector<Game>`?

Comment: ```std::vector<Game*> games;``` @anastaciu

Comment: dont use raw pointers, use shared_ptr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a vector of `Game` pointers, that is the type of object it will accept, therefore `g1`, `g2` and `g3` must be pointers:

```
Game *g1, *g2, *g3;
std::vector <Game*> gameSet;

g1 = new Game(); //intialize pointers
g2 = new Game();
g3 = new Game();
//...
i.setGames(gameSet);
```

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SkicjBViYvIfmpGW)

Note that using raw pointers is not really a good practice these days, it's best to use smart pointers, look into that.

[What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/6865932)

Comment: that gives me a segmentation fault core(dump)

Comment: @FSJ, I made you a live demo, add it to the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
i.setGames(&gameSet);
```

needs `setGames` taking pointer to the `std::vector<Game>`. That means the following function signature

```
void Instructor::setGames(std::vector<Game> *value);
```

what you have is const ref to simple `std::vector<Game*>`

```
void Instructor::setGames(const std::vector<Game*> &value);
```

Obviously they are different types and you have the error.

---

You need simply `const std::vector<Game>& value`

```
void Instructor::setGames(const std::vector<Game>& value)
{
    games = value; // also change the type of games  to be std::vector<Game>
}
```

and in the main

```
  Game g1, g2, g3;
  std::vector <Game> gameSet{ g1, g2, g3};
  i.setGames(gameSet);
```

Comment: Is there no way to fix this without changing ``` std::vector<Game*> games;``` ?

Comment: @FSJ Okay, then the following is the answer. Along with ` i.setGames(gameSet);`. But you don't need ` std::vector<Game*>`.